# problem in Printing A Webpage

Tags: html, jsp

There Is A Date Picker Code In my Program (Of Course We Placed A Calendar Picture In The Web Page) The Problem Now Is That How Can We Be Able Not To Include The Picture Of The Calendar Picture In Printing?

Comment: Capitalizing every word makes your post very hard to read

Comment: @moustafa: do you need more information in order to accept an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use a specific CSS for printing: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate the dom (remove the image) before printing and insert it back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The picture is most likely a background image. Browsers don't print background images by default. You'll need to activate printing of background images (and colors) in your browsers options.

If that's not a option you'll need to change your code, so that the image becomes a normal image instead of a background image.

Answer (score 1):

First You should clarify what is Date Picker - is it Your custom code, or Jquery's one. If its javascript widget as with Jquery, its a common problem with different browsers. My suggestion would be - try YUI calendar instead, it shows well on IE, Firefox and even old Opera. Example:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/formtxt.html
By the way, Jquery's DatePicker shows well in Firefox 3.6.